# How do I animate a UIImageView that was created programatically upon button click? (Each button click creates a new UIImageView with the same image)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I have a code that creates a new UIImageView everytime a button is clicked and that UIImageView is then animated. However, whenever the button is clicked after it is clicked for the first time, I think the animation applied to the second UIImageView that is created affects the first UIImageView. In other words, both start to move very fast (much faster that programmed). This is my code:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
var imageName: String = "ImageName"
var image = UIImage(named: imageName)
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 50,height: 50)
view.addSubView(imageView)
moveIt(imageView)
}

func moveIt(_ imageView: UIImageView) {
UIView.animate(withDuration:TimeInterval(0.00001), delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
imageView.center.x+=3
}, completion: {(_) in self.moveIt(imageView)
})
}
```

I am relatively new with code and swift. Thanks in advance because I cannot quite seem to figure this out.

Comment: can you try explaining the issue with animations again ? i am confused as to what is happening when you press the button for the second time.

Comment: both, the new image and the previous one begin to move very fast. Much faster than the speed the first image was moving at. I tried lowering the speed from 10 to 3 but I faced the same issue.

Comment: remove self.moveIt(imageView) from competition block, and try to animate at once shot with specific time interval

Comment: the self.moveIt(imageView) is essential in the completion block. This is because I am going to add a function that checks the status of the image while it is animating and stop the animation if something is wrong. Also, I have the same issue when I remove it and try animating it in one shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to do a whole bunch of chained animations every 0.00001 seconds. Most things on iOS have a time resolution of ≈ .02 seconds.

You are trying to run an animation every 10 microseconds and move the image view 10 points each step. That comes to an animation of a million points per second. **Don't do that**.

Just create a single animation that moves the image view to it's final destination over your desired time-span. The system will take care of pacing the animation for you. (Say you move it 100 pixels in 0.3 seconds. Just specify a duration of 0.3 seconds, and the body of the animation moves the image view by 100 pixels. There you go. It will just work.

Note that your image views don't have any auto-layout constraints, so they will likely act strangely once the animation is complete.

Comment: I have the same error that occurs though when I decrease the 10 to let's say 3. The animation of the first UIImageView is nice and slow when I click the button for the first time. But when I click it for the second time, both the first UIImageView and the new one move much much faster

Comment: your approach is fundamentally flawed. Don't do it that way.

Comment: If the first button click gives good results it is a happy accident. I would expect it to animate absurdly fast, and never stop.

Comment: That is true. I have not added a way to stop it yet. You are right. I increased the time duration. And it now works as I wanted it to. I am not sure why it worked when I clicked the button the first time with the time duration very low

Comment: If you use a single animation that animates it to it's final destination in a single time interval, you won't have to stop it. It will animate to it's final destination, stop, and you're done. You were doing it wrong, and need to study UIView animations until you get it. Do NOT try create animations with a gazillion tiny steps. That defeats the whole purpose of system driven animation.

Comment: And bear in mind that iOS refreshes the screen every 1/60th of a second (a little over 0.02 seconds.) Any animation duration of 1/60th of a second is a single screen refresh, and intervals smaller than that are meaningless.

Comment: There is a UIView animation that will let you animate a view through a complex curved path automatically. (see the docs on `animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`